# xdebug зависает на первой строчке кода

Tags: php, yii2, сервер, xdebug

Пытаюсь настроить дебаг на удаленке, после запуска сприпт тормозит на первой строчке кода и дальше ничего не происходит, когда я ставлю брекпоинт на первую строчку кода я могу ее словить, как только я ставлю ее на вторую или где-то дальше по коду, делаю обновление страницы и дальше вечная загрузка, хотя на локалке с теме же настройками я нормально могу дебажить код, что не так?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том что xdedug версии 2.7 (на текущий момент самая новая) не хочет работать с PHPSTORM 2018.1
По этому всем у кого такая проблема обновляете шторм до самой новой версии или снижаете дебаг до 2.6